# I’m trying to set the results in GUI instead of console

Tags: java, user-interface, encryption, netbeans

The code in console was like this: now i want the user input the text in JTextField, and the key will be value in JButton, and the output in another JTextFeild. The user will click on button to encrypt the text. And there will be three keys. But it its ok to set the code for each key instead of putting new button for that and using if else. Could anyone please help me its hard dealing with bytes[]

```
BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter Text that you want to encrypt:");
String plainText = userInput.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter the key:");
String key = userInput.readLine();
byte[] encrypted = MARS.encrypt(plainText.getBytes(), key.getBytes())
System.out.println("Plain text: " + plainText);
System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + new String(encrypted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a Swing application which encrypts a string using a key after pressing a button. It is quite a lot of code, but it should create a window like this one:

[image]

I am using Base64 before displaying the encrypted byte array in the result text field.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class EncryptFrame {

    private static final Dimension DEFAULT_FIELD_DIM = new Dimension(300, 20);

    private static JTextField textField;

    private static JTextField keyField;
    private static JTextField resultField;

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Encrypter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = createPanel();
        JButton encryptButton = new JButton("Encrypt");
        final Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(encryptButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        encryptButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String toEncrypt = textField.getText().trim();
            String key = keyField.getText().trim();
            if (!toEncrypt.isEmpty() && !key.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    byte[] res = encrypt(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), toEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    resultField.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(res));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
                        | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e1) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Text or key cannot be empty.");
            }
        });

        textField.requestFocusInWindow();

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        addTextField(panel, grid, gbc);
        addKeyField(panel, gbc);
        addResultField(panel, gbc);
        return panel;
    }

    private static void addResultField(JPanel panel, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        resultField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(resultField, gbc);
    }

    private static void addKeyField(JPanel panel, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel keyLabel = new JLabel("Key:");
        panel.add(keyLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        keyField = new JTextField();
        keyField.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_FIELD_DIM);
        panel.add(keyField, gbc);
    }

    private static void addTextField(JPanel panel, GridBagLayout grid, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        panel.setLayout(grid);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.ipadx = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 10;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 2, 2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Text:");
        panel.add(text, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(DEFAULT_FIELD_DIM);
        panel.add(textField, gbc);
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] value) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] k = new byte[16];
        final boolean lessThanKey = key.length < k.length;
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, k, 0, lessThanKey ? key.length : k.length);
        if (lessThanKey) {
            int diff = Math.abs(key.length - k.length);
            // Pad with 1
            IntStream.range(0, diff).forEach(i -> k[key.length + i] = '1');
        }
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        return cipher.doFinal(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```